# Confused about which meaning is to choose

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses, clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

Let's look at the following sentence.

**Working hard, Ram will definitely succeed**.

I think the sentence could have two meanings.

1. ***There is a condition that if Ram works hard , he will definitely succeed***.
2. ***Ram is someone who works hard and he will succeed***.This is a reduced form. How it's reduced is here,

*Ram, who works hard, will definitely succeed*.

=*Ram, working hard, will definitely succeed*.

=*Working hard, Ram will definitely succeed*. (We often place the participle phrase at the beginning)

Is my concept correct? I'm so confused. Please help me out. If my explanation is correct, which meaning is to choose? 1 or 2 ?

Comment: It isn't a natural way to express either meaning. (1) **If he works hard...** (2) **As he works hard...**

Comment: @KateBunting please answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

*Working hard, Ram will definitely succeed* is not a very natural sentence *because* it is ambiguous.

To express your first meaning, you should say **If he works hard, Ram will succeed.**

To express your second meaning, you could say **As/because/since he works hard, Ram will succeed.**

Comment: And what about the reduction? Is the way of reducing the second sentence correct ?

Comment: We often say " opening the door, he entered the room". Here one action occurs just after the other action and the time difference between them is very less. This is why I interpret the meaning of the sentence like the first one.

Comment: @Sahil Laskar You have given us one sentence and two interpretations, but you are asking about the _second sentence_. As Kate Bunting said, your sentence isn't a natural way to express either of your meanings: we wouldn't usually say it. So I don't think it will be helpful to discuss its meanings. We do say "Opening the door, he entered the room". The meaning is clear. But "Opening the door, Ram will definitely enter" is awkward. It needs explaining. We would find a better way to say it.

Comment: @KateBunting  Are these two reductions grammatically correct? Do they make sense ?

1.My brother, who has called you, loves you.
=My brother, having called you, loves you.
=Having called you, my brother loves you.

2.My sister, who lives in Delhi, knows you.
=My sister, living in Delhi,knows you.
=Living in Delhi,my sister knows you.

Please clear my confusion.

Comment: They don't make sense because they imply (1) that the brother has started to feel love because of the telephone call, and (2) that the sister knows the person because she lives in Delhi. (You could possibly say _Living in Delhi, my sister may have met you_, but it would be more natural to say _As she lives in Delhi..._)